# Powershell - Function returning different result inside vs outside

Tags: powershell

I have written a function in PowerShell, for use with excel, to turn a number into its corresponding letter in the alphabet. If number > 26, then we will loop until the number is less than 26 and spit out 2 letters. So 13 = M and 28 = AB.

When I run the function and use a return inside of it, I get the expected result, but when I call the function later It always returns S regardless of the input. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
$alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

function GetColumnLetter($columnNumber){
    if ($columnNumber -gt 26) 
    {
        $runningColumnCount = $columnNumber
        $loopCount = 0
        while ($runningColumnCount -gt 26) 
        {
            $runningColumnCount = $runningColumnCount - 26
            $loopCount++
        }
        #Get First Letter
        $subStringIndex = $loopCount-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $columnLetter1 = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
        #Get Second Letter
        $subStringIndex = $runningColumnCount-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $columnLetter2 = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
        #Combine Column Letters
        $columnLetter = $columnLetter1+$columnLetter2
    } 
    else 
    {
        $subStringIndex = $columnNumber-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $columnLetter = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
    }

    return $columnLetter
}

GetColumnLetter 27
return $columnLetter
```

And the two returns show this and I would expect them both to be AA in this example:

```
AA
S
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Santiago said, this is because you have `$columnLetter` defined previously outside of the function. If you closed PowerShell and tried again from a clean session the problem would not present itself.

As a side note, this could be greatly simplified. To get the first letter you can divide the input by 26, dropping the remainder using the `[math]::Truncate()` method. As you already had, you only do this if the input is larger than 26, so:

```
if($columnNumber -gt 26){
    $col1=[math]::Truncate($columnNumber/26)-1
    $ltr1=$alphabet.Substring($col1,1)
}
```

For the second letter, the `%` operator will perform the same thing as your loop does, reducing 27 to 1, or 87 to 9. Finding the largest multiple of the second number that is smaller than the first, and subtracting it from the first. You can use that to get the second letter, which is sometimes the only letter.

```
$col2=$columnNumber%26-1
$ltr2=$alphabet.Substring($col2,1)
```

Then you just join `$ltr1` and `$ltr2`. Personally I'd throw in a check to ake sure the input is valid, and include the alphabet inside the function so that it is not relying on having that externally defined, but that is pretty simple. In the end you could do that with:

```
function GetColumnLetter($columnNumber){
    if($columnNumber -lt 1){throw "Column number must be 1 or higher";break}
    $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if($columnNumber -gt 26){
        $col1=[math]::Truncate($columnNumber/26)-1
        $ltr1=$alphabet.Substring($col1,1)
    }
    $col2=$columnNumber%26-1
    $ltr2=$alphabet.Substring($col2,1)
    $ltr1,$ltr2 -join ''
}
```